# How to use SWRevealViewController to open a side menu from a UITabBarItem in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working on a project that I want to incorporate SWRevealViewController with. I was able to get my slide in menu showing with it showing when clicking on the menu button with code below:

`if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}`

but I am now trying to do the same thing, but from a UITabBarItem when clicked. I don't have any code written yet, but I am just asking how I can go about doing this.

[Here are the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4oTc.png)  to show what I want to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: did you achieve this? Im looking for the same. could you pls help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. It works for me.

```
class ViewController: UITabBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    tabBar.delegate = self
}
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if(item.tag == 0){
                self.revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
        }
}
```